# How do I read a file into a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

Good afternoon,

I am currently working on reading a file in the format of

```
5 5
0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0
```

into a 2D array.

The first line is the row length and column length for the 2D array (ie. 5x5).

The proceeding lines are given input values(values themselves are not important only that they are integers) which need to be read into a 2D array such that array[0][0] = 0, array[0][1] = 0 etc.

What I am currently suck on, is reading the contents of the file after the first line and displaying itWhat I have thus far is,

```
public static void importFile(String fileName) throws IOException 
{
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;

    int[][] numArray = null;

    try {
        int count = 0;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
           count++;

            if (count == 1) 
            {
                String[] tokenizer = line.split("\\s+");

                rows = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer[0]);
                System.out.println(rows);

                cols = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer[1]);
                System.out.println(cols);

                numArray = new int[rows][cols];

            } // end of if statement
            else if(count > 1)
            {
                String[] tokenizer = line.split("   ");

                    for(int j = 0; j < tokenizer.length; j++)
                    {
                        numArray[rows][j] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer[j]);
                        System.out.print(numArray[rows][j] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");

                rows++;

            } // end of else if

        }// end of while loop

    } //end of try statement
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("The code throws an exception");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } 

    System.out.println("I am printing the matrix: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < cols; j++)
            System.out.print(numArray[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println("");
    }  
} // end of import file
```

} // end of class
The output is as given

```
Please enter the file you'd like to use: 
data4.txt
5
5
The code throws an exception
5
I am printing the matrix: 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: You are never writing into numArray

Comment: @sdir. Well, that is not the main issue. Integer array will take `0` as default value anyways. I know this wrong, we need to populate values from file. But the problem is because of something else.

Comment: @Only1Realme.. The problem is, you are reading `5` as character `'5'`, and then storing it in integer variable. Thus you will not get `5` as `int`, rather it's `ASCII Code` which is `53`. Apart from this problem, you are really making your job complex. Follow the approach as shown in @jlordo's answer.

Comment: replace `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` with `e.printStackTrace();` and show the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had an extended discussion under my other answer. Since your code shows that you tried (and are pretty close), I'll post a robust solution to your problem. I completely rewrote it, because your program has many little bugs, and it would have been more work to elaborate on each one of it. The following method will read a file of your specified format and return the resulting `int[][]`. If there is an error in your file, the method will tell you ;)

```
public static int[][] importFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    int[][] numArray;
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There was no 1st line.");
    }
    String[] dimensions = line.split("\\s+");
    try {
        int rows = Integer.parseInt(dimensions[0]);
        int cols = Integer.parseInt(dimensions[1]);
        // TODO: check for negative values.
        numArray = new int[rows][cols];
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("First line of file has to be 'rows cols'");
    }

    int row = 0; 

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && row < numArray.length) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        if (tokens.length > numArray[row].length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too many values provided in matrix row " + row);
        }
        // to less values will be filled with 0. If you don't want that
        // you have to uncomment the next 3 lines.
        //if (tokens.length < numArray[row].length) {
        //  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not enough values provided in matrix row " + row);
        //}
        for(int column = 0; column < tokens.length; column++) {
            try {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(tokens[column]);
                numArray[row][column] = value; 
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non numeric value found in matrix row " + row + ", column " + column);
            }
        }
        row++;
    }
    if (line != null) {
        // there were too many rows provided.
        // Superflous ones are ignored.
        // You can also throw exception, if you want.
    }
    if (row < numArray.length) {
        // There were too less rows in the file. If that's OK, the
        // missing rows will be interpreted as all 0.
        // If that's OK with you, you can comment out this whole
        // if block
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected " + numArray.length + " rows, there only were " + row);
    }
    try {
        reader.close(); // never forget to close a stream.
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    return numArray;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a bit more experience than this than me.  I substituted your code, and as promised works beautifully.  Thank you again jlordo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating things. If the file format can be assumed to always be correct, you can safely use

```
String[] tokenizer = line.split(" "); // you have this line of code already.
rows = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer[0]);
cols = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer[1]);
```

This will solve your problem reading the first line.

Your problem is this line of code:

```
rows = tempLine;
```

The way you set the value to `tempLine` (`int tempLine = line.charAt(i);`), you are getting the `int` value of a `char`. The `int` value of the `char` `'5'` is not 5, it is 53, because that's the ASCII code for the character `'5'`.

Comment: This solved my problem with the first line, I will look into reading the contents of the file now with the appended code changes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `rows = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer[0]);
cols = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer[1]);` falls into the catch statement of the try, when I try to print `System.out.println(rows);` `System.out.println(cols);` it produces said error.

Comment: your error says the input is `"5,5"`. In your question you say the input is `"5 5"`. My answer is for input `"5 5"`. If you want the version with the comma, you have to use `String[] tokenizer = line.split(",");`. You have to be exact with your specifications. The file format you posted does not contain a comma. Your error message says there is a comma. also, write this into your catch block: `e.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: `Please enter the file you'd like to use: 
data4.txt
test1
test2
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5,5"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at (load.java:44)`   `static NumberFormatException forInputString(String s) {
        return new NumberFormatException("For input string: \"" + s + "\"");`

Comment: I put this in my code as suggested and this was the message I received from the e.printStackTrace();

Comment: @Only1Realme: It's like I said. Your input contains `"5,5"`. The file format provided in your question does not contain a comma. The code in my answer expects `"5 5"`, and not `"5,5"`. You have to define a clear specification for your input.

Comment: That is the thing, in the file, it reads literally "5 5"  There are no "," in the file.  Therefore in the `String[] tokenizer = line.split(" ");` it is expecting there to be a space.

Comment: @Only1Realme: In the `else` block, try replacing `String[] tokenizer = line.split("   ");` with `String[] tokenizer = line.split("\\s+");` (The one with the multiple blanks, it doesn't show it right in the comments).

Comment: I realized that I had a bufferedreader declared both as 'in' and as 'reader' after removing that it prints out the rows/columns.  However, I fear I may run into the same sort of issue when advancing to the second line etc.

Comment: @Only1Realme: Also, your for loops have are full of errors. I'll try to write a new answer correcting your mistakes.

Comment: After the bufferedreader 'in' was removed, either the `String[] tokenizer = line.split(" ");` or the `String[] tokenizer = line.split("\\s+");` seem to work

Comment: working code has been appended to my original post.  It still wants to throw and exception, so I will have to look into that further, other than that everything seems to be fine.  I appreciate your help and diligence in answer my questions.

Comment: No, it's not working. Just try it with some different numbers than all zero. Everything below the first row will be 0, because you are catching an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I guess, you are correct, I just tried a different file with [0 0 0 1 0] and it only read 0's into the output

Answer (score 0):

for first line:

```
if (count == 1) {
                String[] tokenizer = line.split(" ");
                row=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer[0]);
                col=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer[1]);
                System.out.println("There are " + cols + " colums");
                numArray = new int[row][col];
            } // end of if statement
```

for filling the array

```
            String[] tokenizer = line.split(" ");
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            numArray[0][j]=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer[j]);      //fill the array from tokenizer
            }
```

Comment: `row=tokenizer[0];` will not work, because because `tokenizer[0]` is a `char` and `row` is an `int`. E.g. the `char` `5` will become the `int` 53 (ASCII Code). All other assignments are wrong for the same reason.

Comment: That can be commented instead of downvote. i'm not doing this on the ide. i'm just writing it directly as ans.

Comment: It has nothing to do whether you use an IDE or not, because there were no syntax errors. It was just plain wrong (even repeated the mistake OPs question was basically about [his `int` values were 53, when he expected 5, the same as in the code you originally posted]). I'll remove my -1 because you fixed the errors.

Comment: agree with you! but if that on ide, it will not be the case because it will show the line error.

Comment: No, IDE would not show an error! No compile time error, no runtime error. Only different output than expected. If you explain yourself like that, you should always use an IDE before posting here, because low qualitiy answers are no help to anyone.

Comment: Yes, my bad. OP originally used `charAt()`, which would be like `int x = '5';` and would have worked. Anyway, you have just proven yourself that you should always use your IDE before posting code here, to avoid answers containing errors.

Comment: Sometimes its not possible specially for simple problems. :)